# get_post orderby not working in plugin

Tags: attachments, get-posts, order, php

Please take a look at the loops below, I'm having issues trying to order the attachment by title, name, and modified.

```
<?php
                        foreach ($instance['data'] as $id) :
                                $args = array(
                                    'include' => $id,
                                    'post_type' => 'attachment',                                    
                                    'posts_per_page' => -1,
                                    'post_status' => 'any',
                                    'orderby' => 'title',
                                    'order' => 'DESC',                                  
                                );
                                $data_attach = get_posts($args);
                                foreach ($data_attach as $data) :                                   
                                    ?>          
                                    <?php print_r($data->ID);?>                                     
                                    <?php
                                endforeach;                                
                        endforeach;
                        ?>
```

Print_R's

print_r($instance['data']);

```
Array ( [0] => 1686 [1] => 1628 [2] => 1027 [3] => 1022 [4] => 1045 [5] => 1029 )
```

---

print_r($data->ID);

```
1686 1628 1027 1022 1045 1029
```

Comment: Did you try 'orderby' => 'menu_order' to see if that changes the order at all because I have doubts that WP will do the sorting for attachments.

Comment: I've just tried it. Getting the same results. This is the print_r 1686 1628 1027 1022 1045 1029

Comment: Yes, so I think you have to manually sort the results. Wordpress is not going to do it for you there.

Comment: However, if I do not use the include in $ args it worked but this is not I wanted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't get any ordering, because you are making multiple `get_posts()` calls and only retrieve a *single* post in each of them. You cannot order a single post. :)

You need to get rid of outermost loop and just pass a *set* of IDs (that would be your `$instance['data']`) to retrieve via single `get_posts()` call.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I still couldnt figure out how to pass a set of IDs without using a loop to retrive it. Please show a me code. $instance ['data'] is an Array.

Comment: `'include' => $instance ['data']`

Answer (score 0):

Like I said, in your custom scenario, after getting the results, here is your how you can do it:

```
$data_attach = get_posts($args);
        $title_array = array();

        foreach ($data_attach as $data) :                                   
            $title_array[] = $data->post_title;
        endforeach;

        sort($title_array);
            foreach ($title_array as $key => $val) {
                echo $val . "<br />";
            }
```

Also, refer to this : http://php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php

Comment: Hi Wali, those numbers are actually attachment ids. Im trying to sort by attachment titles, names, dates or modified.

Comment: I just edited my Answer to give you a better idea of how to sort the results.